# Can't even migrate Magento 1.9 with sample data to Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, migration, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration-tool

I am learning the process of migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2. I have installed Magento 1.9.3.10 (with sample data) and Magento 2.2.6 (no sample data) on one server. When I run Data Migration Tool, it fails with many "Source fields are not mapped" errors. I have attached a screenshot.

The reason it fails is that it doesn't know how to migrate several tables. For example, there is a "move" record in `map.xml`, saying that `sales_flat_creditmemo` corresponds to `sales_creditmemo`. But the first table has a field `base_customer_balance_amount` and the second table doesn't have it. And there is no record in default config that would handle this field.

It seems Data Migration Tool is even not capable of migrating a basic configuration. It means either sample data for Magento 1.9 messes up database schema, or I am doing something wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Every time I've run a migration, I ran into the same error.

In map.xml, you'll have to add those fields to the ignore section of the source.

Like this:

> ```
>         <ignore>
>             <document>sales_flat_order_address</document>
>         </ignore>
> ```

If you're certain they should exist, you may need to add them as such:

> ```
>         <rename>
>             <document>sales_flat_order_address</document>
>             <to>equivalent magento2 table</to>
>         </rename>
> ```

Repeat until the errors are gone. It's tedious, but that's what I had to do each time I've migrated.